# How to show six products in slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using [bootsnipp.com](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/m0q1y) and also [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/rtpHarry/pen/ogVord)
but in slider only one item is showing instead of 6. How can I show six items in slider and when click on next and previous button show next or previous item?
Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#itemslider').carousel({
    interval: 3000
  });

  $('.carousel-showmanymoveone .item').each(function() {
    var itemToClone = $(this);

    for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
      itemToClone = itemToClone.next();

      if (!itemToClone.length) {
        itemToClone = $(this).siblings(':first');
      }

      itemToClone.children(':first-child').clone()
        .addClass("cloneditem-" + (i))
        .appendTo($(this));
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#slider-text {
  padding-top: 40px;
  display: block;
}

#slider-text .col-md-6 {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#slider-text h2 {
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

#slider-text h2::after {
  border-top: 2px solid #c7c7c7;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 35px;
  width: 100%;
}

#itemslider h4 {
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 10px auto 3px;
}

#itemslider h5 {
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 3px auto 2px;
}

#itemslider h6 {
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  ;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 2px auto 5px;
}

.badge {
  background: #b20c0c;
  position: absolute;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 31px;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #b20c0c;
  top: 5px;
  right: 25%;
}

#slider-control img {
  padding-top: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  #slider-control img {
    padding-top: 70px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}

.carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-control {
  width: 4%;
  background-image: none;
}

.carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-control.left {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-control.right {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.carousel-showmanymoveone .cloneditem-1,
.carousel-showmanymoveone .cloneditem-2,
.carousel-showmanymoveone .cloneditem-3,
.carousel-showmanymoveone .cloneditem-4,
.carousel-showmanymoveone .cloneditem-5 {
  display: none;
}

@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner>.active.left,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner>.prev {
    left: -50%;
  }
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner>.active.right,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner>.next {
    left: 50%;
  }
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner>.left,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner>.prev.right,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner>.active {
    left: 0;
  }
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner .cloneditem-1 {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 768px) and (transform-3d),
all and (min-width: 768px) and (-webkit-transform-3d) {
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner>.item.active.right,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner>.item.next {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(50%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(50%, 0, 0);
    left: 0;
  }
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner>.item.active.left,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner>.item.prev {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
    left: 0;
  }
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner>.item.left,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner>.item.prev.right,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner>.item.active {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    left: 0;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 992px) {
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner>.active.left,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner>.prev {
    left: -16.666%;
  }
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner>.active.right,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner>.next {
    left: 16.666%;
  }
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner>.left,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner>.prev.right,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner>.active {
    left: 0;
  }
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner .cloneditem-2,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner .cloneditem-3,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner .cloneditem-4,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner .cloneditem-5,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner .cloneditem-6 {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 992px) and (transform-3d),
all and (min-width: 992px) and (-webkit-transform-3d) {
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner>.item.active.right,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner>.item.next {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(16.666%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(16.666%, 0, 0);
    left: 0;
  }
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner>.item.active.left,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner>.item.prev {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-16.666%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-16.666%, 0, 0);
    left: 0;
  }
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner>.item.left,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner>.item.prev.right,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner>.item.active {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:300,400,700&subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href="index.css" />
<!--<script src='index.js'></script>-->

<script src='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>


<!--Item slider text-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="slider-text">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2>NEW COLLECTION</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Item slider-->
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
      <div class="carousel carousel-showmanymoveone slide" id="itemslider">
        <div class="carousel-inner">

          <div class="item active">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
              <a href="#"><img src="https://s12.postimg.org/655583bx9/item_1_180x200.png" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
              <h4 class="text-center">MAYORAL SUKNJA</h4>
              <h5 class="text-center">4000,00 RSD</h5>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
              <a href="#"><img src="https://s12.postimg.org/41uq0fc4d/item_2_180x200.png" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
              <h4 class="text-center">MAYORAL KOŠULJA</h4>
              <h5 class="text-center">4000,00 RSD</h5>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
              <a href="#"><img src="https://s12.postimg.org/dawwajl0d/item_3_180x200.png" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
              <span class="badge">10%</span>
              <h4 class="text-center">PANTALONE TERI 2</h4>
              <h5 class="text-center">4000,00 RSD</h5>
              <h6 class="text-center">5000,00 RSD</h6>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
              <a href="#"><img src="https://s12.postimg.org/5w7ki5z4t/item_4_180x200.png" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
              <h4 class="text-center">CVETNA HALJINA</h4>
              <h5 class="text-center">4000,00 RSD</h5>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
              <a href="#"><img src="https://s12.postimg.org/e2zk9qp7h/item_5_180x200.png" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
              <h4 class="text-center">MAJICA FOTO</h4>
              <h5 class="text-center">4000,00 RSD</h5>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
              <a href="#"><img src="https://s12.postimg.org/46yha3jfh/item_6_180x200.png" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
              <h4 class="text-center">MAJICA MAYORAL</h4>
              <h5 class="text-center">4000,00 RSD</h5>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div id="slider-control">
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#itemslider" data-slide="prev">
            <img src="https://s12.postimg.org/uj3ffq90d/arrow_left.png" alt="Left" class="img-responsive">
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#itemslider" data-slide="next">
            <img src="https://s12.postimg.org/djuh0gxst/arrow_right.png" alt="Right" class="img-responsive">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to show six products in slider? Also slider product should not move when mouse cursor is on the slider.

Comment: try this link https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/8xDZ i think it.s solve your solution

Comment: yaa, i know this one is alternative solution but i want to  use this slider in e-commerce to show product and hence i want that one product slide at a time

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The above code has not error. Actually we need to put jquery file before  end body tag Because each time jquery file add and remove class. Hence for this dynamic change we have to put before end body tag not in head section. We all know whatever defined in head section all those include only once.

Comment: Can anyone tell me the above code whatever i posted is not working with col-md-3 or col-md-4 properly.So, What i have to change in these three files?

Answer (score 0):

Change the width of slider-container and change the width of item,Let's say the width of the container for the slides is 100% then for the slider elements 100% / 6. to stop moving just add:

```
$('slider').hover(function(){
    clearInterval(variableThatHoldsSetInterval);
},function(){
    variableThatHoldsSetInterva = setInterval(function(){},time);
})
```

Comment: i am using bootstrap and already i used container-fluid and responsive (col-md col-sm) etc. Can you tell me exactly where i have to change? I attached all three files

Comment: Your items have relative width and the number of items changes Dependent on permission class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2" , if xs - 1item, if sm - 2items, if md -6 items, if you want allways have 6 items on all devises, leave only class="col-xs-12"

Comment: I want that to show 6 items on lg and medium 3 items on small(may reduce) and only one item on xs(extra small)

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery('#client-carousel').carousel({interval: 5000, pause: "hover"});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <div class="our-clients">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="client">
        <div class="client-logo">
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="clients-title">
              <h3 class="title">Our Clients</h3>
              
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="row">
              <div id="client-carousel" class="client-carousel carousel slide">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                  <div class="item active">
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6 item animate_afc d1">
                      <div class="item-inner"><a href="#"><img alt="cablenet" src="img/clientslogo/1.jpg"></a></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6 item animate_afc d2">
                      <div class="item-inner"><a href="#"><img alt="cablenet" src="img/clientslogo/2.jpg"></a></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6 item animate_afc d3">
                      <div class="item-inner"><a href="#"><img alt="cablenet" src="img/clientslogo/3.jpg"></a></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6 item animate_afc d4">
                      <div class="item-inner"><a href="#"><img alt="cablenet" src="img/clientslogo/4.jpg"></a></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6 item animate_afc d5">
                      <div class="item-inner"><a href="#"><img alt="cablenet" src="img/clientslogo/5.jpg"></a></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6 item animate_afc d6">
                      <div class="item-inner"><a href="#"><img alt="cablenet" src="img/clientslogo/6.jpg"></a></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6 item">
                      <div class="item-inner"><a href="#"><img alt="cablenet" src="img/clientslogo/7.jpg"></a></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6 item">
                      <div class="item-inner"><a href="#"><img alt="cablenet" src="img/clientslogo/8.jpg"></a></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6 item">
                      <div class="item-inner"><a href="#"><img alt="cablenet" src="img/clientslogo/9.jpg"></a></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6 item">
                      <div class="item-inner"><a href="#"><img alt="cablenet" src="img/clientslogo/10.jpg"></a></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6 item">
                      <div class="item-inner"><a href="#"><img alt="Upportdash" src="img/clientslogo/11.jpg"></a></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6 item">
                      <div class="item-inner"><a href="#"><img alt="Upportdash" src="img/clientslogo/12.jpg"></a></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

try this code i think solve your problem..any modification comment me